# Is it possible to always set 0 in the center of Charts's Y-axis with swift charts lib?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

[image]

According example image I want to create my chart like that. My data entries have both positive and negative values, I want to set 0 in the middle of y-axis everytime.

Is impossible to do that?
Ps. I use Charts library with swift version 5.

Comment: There should be max/min values like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176581/ios-charts-set-minimum-y-axis-range ?

Comment: @Larme Thx you so much, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the biggest number on the Y-axis in the chart's dataSet.

```
let maxValue = max(dataSet)
chart.setChartMinMaxYValues(chartYMin: -(maxValue), chartYMax: maxValue)
```